# How to hide mouse cursor while typing in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mouse-cursor

Has anyone managed to find a workaround solution to [Visual Studio doesn't hide the mouse cursor while typing](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/537390/mouse-pointer-does-not-obey-control-panel-mouse-intellipoint-settings-hide-pointer-while-typing)?

I use both mouse and keyboard while coding. I must say this bug drives me insane since it has a strong impact on Intellisense, forcing popups to blink in and out of existence as I type simply because I have the mouse cursor placed on an identifier. It also affects third-party tools like Devexpress CodeRush or, I suspect, JetBrains ReSharper.

The typical working pattern for someone like me that uses both the mouse and keyboard while coding, involves using the mouse as a quick navigation tool inside the source file. Exactly for this reason we often click locations in code that contain identifiers. On the other hand, the cursor may be far away from one, but if my typing invariably ends up putting an identifier next to the mouse cursor, again intellisense (or third-party tools similar features) snap into existence, blinking in and out as I type; for a very annoying effect.

Comment: Cut the mouse cord.  It is going to hurt for a while, learning the shortcut keystrokes takes some time.  The payoff is big.

Answer (score 3):

Like you, I've had this problem forever.  So I have written a little script that hides the mouse cursor no matter what Windows application you are using.

Note that if you run Visual Studio (or anything) in elevated mode, you'll need to run my utility also in elevated mode.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/Stefan-Z-Camilleri-zz/Windows-Cursor-Hider)

Comment: GitHub link to this script had changed: https://github.com/Stefan-Z-Camilleri-zz/Windows-Cursor-Hider

Answer (score -1):

Windows has a feature that is enabled by default (on windows 7 at least), called "Hide pointer while typing". I must admit that it does not work all the time but it appears to me that is working for you :). It can be disabled from Control Panel -> Mouse -> Pointer Options -> Hide pointer while typing. Because I don't have any other OS installed I can't give you other exact path but I think I discovered it around Windows 98 or Me.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.

Comment: "Hide pointer while typing" does not affect Visual Studio at all. Windows 8/8.1 VS 2010/2012/2013

Comment: Proof: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/537390/mouse-pointer-does-not-obey-control-panel-mouse-intellipoint-settings-hide-pointer-while-typing

Comment: Microsoft doesn't respect Windows settings. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/the-vs-editor-ignores-the-hide-pointer-while-typin/70859